# Creating databases using Zend_Db_Adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm struggling with a part of my application where I am using Zend_Db_Adapter to create a database schema in mysql per client signup.

I have a database script that contains all the DDL to create the tables, I then read the contents of the file and then execute it using the Zend_Db_Adapter.  Following the creation of the database I want to populate it with some data using the same adapter.  However this always fails with an error such as:

> 2011-08-10T14:15:16+01:00 DEBUG (7): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'client_3.users' doesn't exist

Can someone see where in my code it's going slightly wrong?  I've had the MySQL logging up to see any errors and there don't appear to be any, and the DDL script works fine when ran by hand.

```
$databaseName = 'client_' . $clientId;
$createDbStr = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ".$databaseName."; CREATE DATABASE " . $databaseName.";";

            $dbAdapter->getConnection()->exec($createDbStr);

            //we now create the database adapter for the new database on the server
            //as we now populate the user data in the databaes.
            $newDbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'appdbuser',
                'password' => 'appdbpassword',
                'dbname' => $databaseName
            ));


            //we now load the SQL Script that is used to create the database schema.
            $sqlScriptPath = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'datamodel' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'client_schema.sql';
            $fileUtils = new App_FileSystem_FileUtility();
            $sqlScript = "USE ".$databaseName.";";
            $sqlScript .= $fileUtils->getFileContents($sqlScriptPath);

            //debug sql script;
            App_Application_Log::getInstance()->log($sqlScript, Zend_Log::DEBUG);

            //we now create the schema
            $newDbAdapter->getConnection()->exec($sqlScript);


            $usersTable = new Application_Model_UsersTable($newDbAdapter);
            $newUserTableData = array(
                'username' => 'Administrator',
                'fullname' => $contactName',
                'email' => $email,
                'uuid' => App_Security_Uuid::getInstance()->getUuid(),
                'create_date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('now()'),                
            );

            $userId = $usersTable->insert($newUserTableData); //errors here
```

Is there a step that needs to be done from the running of the DDL script before I can start populating it with data?

Thanks,

Grant

Comment: I would try adding a `CREATE TABLE` command to your sqlScript, eg: `$sqlScript = "USE ".$databaseName."; CREATE TABLE test (\`id\` int);";` to try to narrow down the problem.  And I presume the spare `'` at the end of `'fullname' => $contactName',` has somehow got into your post, but isn't in your code?  Presumably it wouldn't even run if it was there, but just checking.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested and same problem no tables created :(.  The ' at the end of the 'fullname' => $contactName' is a post typo.  Code works fine, well it executes ;)

Comment: Ok, lets just try : `$newDbAdapter->getConnection()->exec("CREATE TABLE ".$databaseName.".test (\`id\` int);";` after you exec the create database.

Comment: That worked... I've got an idea on what I need to do now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to this problem now which I hope will help others.

What I did was ensure that the create_schema.sql script had the database names in the DDL

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `dbname`.`users`(
 userid INT,
 username VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I then, in my PHP code did a find replace of the using the str_replace function of the database name with with name of the clients database.

```
$sqlScriptPath = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'datamodel' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'client_schema.sql';
            $fileUtils = new App_FileSystem_FileUtility();            
            $sqlScript = str_replace('dbname', $databaseName, $fileUtils->getFileContents($sqlScriptPath));

            //debug sql script;
            App_Application_Log::getInstance()->log($sqlScript, Zend_Log::DEBUG);

            //we now create the schema
            $newDbAdapter->getConnection()->exec($sqlScript);
```

This then created all the tables and indexes as described in the SQL script.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `$dbAdapter->getConnection()->exec($createDbStr);` will run two SQL statements like you have. Split each into its own statement (the `drop table if exists` and the `create table`)

Comment: the create database is fine, the main issue is the creation of database tables, which seems a bit strange.